# Automate event through oracle table insert with java function call

Tags: java, oracle, comet

I have to call a java function like doProcess() on oracle table after any new data insertion event. For achieving this functionality I created a java scheduler which run on a half an hour interval which checks the data in oracle table which have a flag attribute status (T/F). By default its False and after scheduler works completes its changed as True. But the problem is that Every time i have to run java scheduler to complete this functionality(call  java function like doProcess() on new data insertion) So I want these functionality to be automated without java scheduler. How can I achieve it ???.
I am using java and oracle with weblogic server.
please provide proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your Java code can be stored in database, than you could put the code in Java stored procedure and do the call in database trigger.

2nd way, you can subscribe to change in one separate connection that gets notifications. In this case check DBMS_ALERT (http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ARPLS/DBMS_ALERT.htm#ARPLS351) or DBMS_PIPE

3rd could be any type of queuing, in or out of database

Comment: Thanks igr. I will check and then confirm as an answer.First point is not possible and 3rd point is not explain well so I will only check for second point and then get back to you.